# Visa application for Canada: Should douments in the local language of the consulate's location be translated?

Tags: canada, germany, tourist-visas

I am applying for a tourist visa for Canada, I am living in Germany but I am not from here. I have some documents which are in German and not English, Do I need to translate them to English? or since I am applying here in Germany it would be fine?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to provide a translation of any documents not in English or French, as the  Goverment of [Canada Help Centre notes](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=018&top=4):

> **What language should my supporting documents be in?**
>   Unless we tell you otherwise, all supporting documents must be in English or French.
>
> If it is not in English or French, you must send it with:
>
> - the English or French translation and
> - an [affidavit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#affidavit) from the person who completed the translation and
> - a [certified photocopy](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#certified_photocopy) of the original document

***Glossary links***:

> **Affidavit**
>   A document becomes an affidavit when a person signs the document, in the presence of an authorized person, after taking an oath that what the document says is true and accurate.
>
> An affidavit is often used in order to verify that a translation of a document accurately reflects what is stated in the original language of the document.
>
> **Certified photocopy**
>   A photocopy of an original document. It must be readable and certified as a true copy of the original by an authorized person. The person compares the documents and marks on the photocopy:
>
> - their name and signature
> - their position or title
> - the name of the original document
> - the date they certified the document
> - the phrase “I certify that this is a true copy of the original document.”
>
> In Canada, examples of authorized persons who can certify the copies of your original documents include:
>
> - notary public
> - commissioner of oaths, or
> - commissioner of taking affidavits
>
> Check with your provincial or territorial authorities to be sure who can certify your documents.
>
> Outside Canada, each country has different authorities to certify documents. A notary public may be able to certify your documents, but you should check with your local authorities to be sure.
>
> You and your family members cannot certify copies of your documents.